# ADB bricked android doesn't connect to pc

Tags: boot, boot-loop, unbricking

I have a bricked android BLUBOO X2. I rooted it, changed build.prop to set some settings so that I could boot in Ubuntu Touch(which didn't work). And now I can't boot up anymore at all, it is in boot loop.

I tried booting in recovery and then selected "apply update from ADB". It then says: 'Now send the package you want to apply to the device with "adb sideload < filename>" ... '. I did this once and it showed an error, but the weird thing/problem is that I cannot sideload anything anymore: 'error: device not found'.

I (think I) know it is connected with my (Windows 10) PC because it made a connection and deconnecting sound when booting in recovery.

How can I get my android to be connected or how otherwise can I load a ROM or change the build.prop back?

Comment: Was ADB enabled in Developer Settings before it was bricked? What recovery do you have now? Is there a custom recovery available for your device?

Comment: I don't think I have enabled ADB before. I don't know how to respond to the question: " What" recovery do you have now?. And I wanted to install a custum ROM file, http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/rom-xtraslim-1-0-stock-odex-optimized-t2924150.

Comment: I mean, what is the name of the recovery? Is it the default (stock) recovery that came with the device? Or is it a custom recovery like [TWRP](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/orig-development/recovery-twrp-2-7-1-0-touch-recovery-t2511507) ?

Comment: Just the stock recovery: if I hold power and vol-up I can choose recovery.

Comment: You don't have much options left at the table. If your device supports flashing from fastboot mode, then find a custom recovery for your device and flash or boot into it using fastboot mode. Then either correct the prop file or replace the ROM. If fastboot flashing is not supported, you must find the recovery flashable stock ROM zip for your device and use it to flash your device (you would lose existing data). Another alternative is to use [SP Flash Tool](http://androidmtk.com/smart-phone-flash-tool).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've just messed with the system partition, so there's nothing much to panic.. Here's a stock ROM for your phone:

http://www.needrom.com/category/bluboo/x2-bluebo/ (Choose the ROM for the SAME android version you had before bricking).

The good news is you won't need to lose your data. Everything will be safe.

Download SP Flash Tools, load the scatter file from this ROM, uncheck all the partitions except ANDROID (SYSTEM) as this is the only partition you need to rectify. Click on Download and connect your device. Your device will be unbricked without having to lose any data.

Comment: Good that you found the ROM. Could you please link SP Flash Tools as well? If possible,  link the instructions for its usage as well.

Comment: The flash tool says its an invalid scatter file.

Comment: @Jeroentetje3 Be sure that you're targeting the MTxxxx_Android_Scatter.txt

This is the tutorial that worked perfectly fine for me when I was in the same condition as you: https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-159.html

Also, plz mention the flash tools version that you're using.

Comment: File: MT6592_Android_scatter.txt
Error:
" SP FLASH TOOL ERROR: (8417)

 The load scatter file is invalid!

[HINT]:
Please check the scatter file and select again!"

This is both for 4.4.2 and 4.2.2. I downloaded the .rar from the site you send and unziped them and selected this file from there.

I use SP_Flash_Tool_v5.1532.00.000.zip = latest version. I also used 2 slightly older ones.

Answer (score -1):

if you bricked your phone and the battery is non removable..
just open your back panel.. 
open screws and just cut off the power supply from the battery to phone..
for your reference i have posted a link of how to cut power supply from vivo xshot and restore it

https://moschino2015.wordpress.com/2015/09/18/exquisite-and-easy-to-disassemble-vivo-xshot-teardown-map-tour/
have fun!!

p.s who says battery arent removable??

note :- i am not responsible if u damage the internal circuits or void warranty of your phone!!
do it on ur own risk!
but it worked for me :)

Comment: When people say "removable", they refer to ones that are easily done, i.e. removable back cover and battery with bare hands. No risk of "damage the internal circuits or void warranty". Also, this isn't helpful to solving the brick problem OP is concerned with at all. -1